# Creating an sql query using awk, bash, grep

Tags: sql, bash, awk, grep

I have been trying to parse a Paypal Email and insert the resultant info into a Database of mine. I have most of the code working but I cannot get a Variable to insert into my awk code to create the sql insert query.

```
if [  -f email-data.txt ]; then {
    grep  -e "Transaction ID:" -e "Receipt No: " email-data.txt \
      >> ../temp
    cat ../temp \
      | awk 'NR == 1 {printf("%s\t",$NF)}  NR == 2 {printf("%s\n",$NF)}' \
      >> ../temp1
    awk '{print $1}' $email-data.txt \
      | grep @ \
      | grep -v \( \
      | grep -v href \
      >> ../address
    email_addr=$(cat ../address)
    echo  $email_addr 
    cat ../temp1 \
      | awk '{print "INSERT INTO users (email,paid,paypal_tran,CCReceipt) VALUES"; print "(\x27"($email_addr)"\x27,'1',\x27"$2"\x27,\x27"$3"\x27);"}' \
      > /home/linux014/opt/post-new-member.sql
```

The output looks like the following

```
INSERT INTO users (email,paid,paypal_tran,CCReceipt) VALUES('9MU013922L4775929  9MU013922L4775929',1,'9MU013922L4775929','');
```

Should look like

```
INSERT INTO users (email,paid,paypal_tran,CCReceipt) VALUES('dogcat@gmail.com',1,'9MU013922L4775929','1234-2345-3456-4567');
```

(Names changed to protect the innocent)
The trial data I am using is set out below

```
Apr 18, 2014 10:46:17 GMT-04:00 | Transaction ID: 9MU013922L4775929

You received a payment of $50.00 USD from Dog Cat (dogcat@gmail.com)
Buyer:
Dog Cat
dogcat@gmail.com

Purchase Details 

Receipt No: 1234-2345-3456-4567
```

I cannot figure out why the email-addr is not being inserted properly.

Comment: You might want to scrap this script and use a programming language with an email parser class and mysql classes.  Why re-invent the wheel?  I know that's an annoying answer.  You asked, "How do I make this crazy bicycle work?" and I told you "screw bicycles, use a car."  But honestly, you're pretty much guaranteed to create unmaintainable code this way.  You will be mad at yourself a year from now for using shell utilities to parse an email and generate SQL from it.  I'm sure of that, because I've done the same things in the past.

Comment: Point taken.  Thank you for your candor. I am not well versed in Email Parsers and mysql classes.  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a shell variable inside `awk`. The right way to do that is by creating an `awk` variable using `-v` option.

For example, say `$email` is your shell variable, then

```
... | awk -v awkvar="$email" '{do something with awkvar}' ...
```

Read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-Shell-Variables.html) for more details.

However, having said that, here is how I would try and parse the text file:

```
awk '
/Transaction ID:/ { tran  =  $NF }
/Receipt No:/     { receipt = $NF }
$1 ~ /@/          { email  =  $1 }
END {
     print "INSERT INTO users (email,paid,paypal_tran,CCReceipt) VALUES"; 
     print "("q email q","1","q tran q","q receipt q");"
}' q="'" data.txt
```

#### Output:

```
INSERT INTO users (email,paid,paypal_tran,CCReceipt) VALUES
('dogcat@gmail.com',1,'9MU013922L4775929','1234-2345-3456-4567');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.  As you know it worked right away.  I appreciate your skills and will definitely use this code.  Cheers...

Comment: Simple and powerful, as Bash in general. Thank you